# Does phonegap and cordova supports ARIA roles?

Tags: html, cordova, role, wai-aria

I want use ARIA roles on phonegap build, I tested and the code below didn't worked (the code is an example).

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" role="textbox" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="E-mail" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="tel" role="textbox" id="phone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Phone" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" role="textbox" id="address" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Address" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap does not control this. This question is, does the native webview version for the platform(s) your app supports have control for this?

You can check here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=wai-aria

Phonegap makes use of native platform webviews for applications so functionality is limited to the supports of the native webviews versions you will support for your app. Because webviews are part of an SDK they are usually not the most current version and regularly do not match the support of the browser loaded on the device.

Comment: I'm using a Moto G for testing and everything is updated, the OS, chrome browser, everything! It works in the browser, but when I build with phonegap and install, it just doesnt work anymore... seems like phonegap dont support it! @DawsonLoudon

Comment: The chrome browser won't affect the native application. You need to check for compatibilities with the native webview for the version of the OS you are working with. PhoneGap doesn't support anything on the display end. PhoneGap is a bridge between content in a native webview and the native code/apis. Display issues or HTML5 compatibility is an issue with the OS webview version.